# Parallel push back to a vector of vector

Tags: c++, thread-safety, openmp

I have a vector of vector. I construct this vector in a parallel manner with each index in the vector being dealt with by a single thread. Something similar to this :

```
vector<vector<int> > global_vec(10, vector<int>({}));

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < i * 5; j++)
    {
        global_vec[i].push_back(i);
    }
}
```

I know if I had known the size of each vector beforehand, I could have allocated required size in the beginning and then there would have been no issue. But this can't be done by me and I need to dynamically push back. Is this thread safe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenMP, but if there are, say, 10 threads then each of them could use one element of `global_vec` without interfering with any other thread. That would be safe. But if OpenMP doesn't work like that, or can't be set up like that, and multiple threads could access multiple elements of `global_vec`, then it's not safe.

Comment: @AlainMerigot, but only one thread is modifying the state of a given vector(inside the larger vector of vector) at a time.

Comment: Only the outer `for` loop runs parallel, so each thread uses it's own `vector<int>`. Therefore it is fine.

Comment: off topic(and assuming the code is fine): it may be beneficial to push back into a local vector living in the outer loop to avoid false sharing. after pushing all values, move into the global vec. otherwise multiple threads are hammering onto the same cacheline (in the global vec)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is thread-safe, since the inner vectors are solely modified by one thread. You can omit the `schedule(dynamic)` derivative and still be save.

This becomes a bit clearer, if you get rid of the inner loop using `std::iota`.

```
vector<vector<int> > global_vec(10, vector<int>({}));

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    global_vec[i].resize(i * 5) ;
    std::iota(global_vec[i].begin(), global_vec[i].end(), 0);
}
```

Ps. If your outer vector has a fixed size, consider using a `std::array<vector<int>, 10>` instead.